# db.collectionsname.findOne({mobilenumber: mobilenumber}).feildname

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im not able to fetch the field value i need only the value of the particular field in node js query, but coming undefined

I need the nodejs query of this mongodb query

Answer (score 0):

Try using [projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) into find query to return only values you want.

Also don't forget to use `await` or get the field name into `then`. And, of course, the query should return any document to get the field.

Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jw3vWCl-ZFu) which would be similar in Node:

```js
const value = await db.collectionsname.findOne({mobilenumber: mobilenumber},{_id: 0, field: 1}).fieldname
```

Projection stage is not mandatory but if you only want that value is a good practice not get all document from the DB.